# What is the better way to access state in containers in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have seen there are two ways to access the store in react in containers.
First approach is, accessing the properties directly.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        selectedUser: state.profile.selectedUser,
        trainerBioInfo: state.profile.trainerBioInfo
    };
};
```

Second approach is, accessing the reducer and, in the screen, we get what we want from the reducer.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        profile: state.profile,
        trainer: state.trainer
    };
};
```

Which approach is better to use?

Comment: In the second approach it looks like `selectedUser` and `trainerBioInfo` will both be the exact same thing - `state.profile`... Which doesn't make sense to me. Do you mean the second approach you would sometimes do `profile: state.profile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way makes more sense in my opinion as each key value pair contains the appropriate information.

In the second way they're identical so it's pointless. You may as well just return the following

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
       state
    };
};
```

You'll know when your code can be optimized as the JSX will have things like {this.props.state.profile.selectedUser.name} as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach will give you some abnormal behaviour as the assignment of the variable is not proper.

So the first approach is correct and can be modified like below:

```
const mapStateToProps = { profile } => {
    return {
        selectedUser: profile.selectedUser,
        trainerBioInfo: profile.trainerBioInfo,
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually Changed the second approach. I had mistakenly posted it in a wrong way. So, out of these 2, is the first one the better approach?